# Azure Service Definition: What does the Runtime Execution Context actually do?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

The Azure documentation on the executionContext (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx#Runtime) says the executionContext controls if the runtime environment is "elevated" or not (defaults to non-elevated, "limited"). I noticed, however, that the WaIISHost and w3wp processes are running as elevated, even when the executionContext is defaulted to limited.

[image]

The documentation doesn't explain this. Is there a more verbose explanation of the impact of setting the exectutionContext to "elevated"?

Does using executionContext="true" mean my entire web application runs elevated?

Answer (score 0):

> > Does using executionContext="true" mean my entire web application runs elevated?

`"true"` is not a valid value.

You can set it to `"limited"` or `"elevated"`.  If you set it to `elevated`, in a Worker Role it will run `waworkerhost.exe` as `SYSTEM` instead of `NETWORK SERVICE`.

I'm not sure what it does with web roles.  I've read that it [depends on what version of the Azure SDK you're using](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ae4a8cda-4bdb-4447-b981-047abf444dc1/running-code-with-elevated-privileges?forum=windowsazuredevelopment), and in some versions will only elevate the RoleEntryPoint of the web role, and not the actual web site that is running in IIS.

Answer (score -1):

From the official web site: `the executionContext attribute specifies the privilege level of the startup task, and the taskType attribute specifies how the task will be executed.`

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-startup-tasks/

Comment: The question refers to the ServiceDefinition file, not start-up tasks.

Comment: @Nick startup tasks are defined inside the service definition